# Is it possible that $\Vert I \Vert > 1$ !?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

For any matrix norm, is it possible $\Vert I \Vert > 1$ ?, where $I_{n\times n}$ is identity matrix.

If not, why in some books they write $\Vert I \Vert \geqslant 1 $ ?

Comment: If $||\cdot||$ is a norm then so is $c||\cdot||$ for any constant $c>0$.

Comment: @Winther for some values of $c$ (not sure which off-hand), it will fail to be a multiplicative matrix norm (which is what is usually meant by "matrix norm" as far as I am aware).

Comment: Please be more specific about the context where you've seen this.  As Omnomnomnom's answer points out, an arbitrary norm can take lots of values but an operator norm cannot.  But it's unreasonable to speculate why some books write a particular thing when you don't specify what it is they're writing.  There are plenty of contexts where it's reasonable to say $x \ge 1$ even if $x = 1$ is known — but it's not fair to ask us to dream up possibilities until you find one that matches the reference you already have in front of you.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Good point. If $||\cdot ||$ is a matrix norm then $c||\cdot||$ is only guaranteed to be a matrix norm if $c\geq 1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  For example, we can define the Frobenius norm by
$$
\|A\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{ij}|a_{ij}|^2} = \sqrt{\operatorname{trace}(A^*A)}
$$
in general, we have $\|I\|_F = \sqrt{n}$.  This is a matrix-norm (AKA a sub-multiplicative matrix-norm) in that it is a norm under the usual definition and satisfies $\|AB\|_F \leq \|A\|_F\|B\|_F$.

*(This norm tends to be particularly handy for several reasons.  For one, it is the norm derived from the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product).*

However, note that for any *derived norm* (AKA an operator norm), $\|I\| = 1$ since for any vector norm $|\cdot|$ and any $x$, $|Ix| = |x|$.

Comment: No problem!${}$

Comment: It might be worth adding that $\|I\|\geq 1$ for any submultiplicative norm $\|\cdot\|$ since $\|I\|\neq 0$ ($I\neq 0$) and $\|I\|=\|I\cdot I\|\leq\|I\|\|I\|$, hence $1\leq\|I\|$.